# How to make text indent in second line capitation in HTML

Tags: html

I don't know how to make text indent in my capitation in second line in html. I tried giving hardcoded whitespaces but in next in my HTML document they appear as grey field.

```
<capitation>
<span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;">xxx</span>
<span style="font-size: 12px;">YYYY</span> 
<span style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 12px;">YYYYY</span> 
<span style="font-size: 12px">YYYYY</span>
<br>
<span style="font-size: 12px "> XXXXXX</span> 
<span style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 12px;"> xxxxxxxx</span> 
<span style="font-size: 12px;">XXXXXXX</span>  
<br>
<br>
</capitation>
```

Its appears as

```
XXXX! YYYY
ZZZZ
```

and I want

```
XXXXX! YYYYYY
       ZZZZZZ
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is a bit naff mate.

Inline CSS everywhere and so on.
It's not how I would write it. But you could use padding-left.

Jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ev88su57/1/

```
<capitation>
<span class="bold">xxx</span>
<span>YYYY</span> 
<span class="bold">YYYYY</span> 
<span>YYYYY</span>
<br>

<span class="indent"> XXXXXX</span> 
<span class="bold"> xxxxxxxx</span> 
<span>XXXXXXX</span>  
<br>
</capitation>
```

CSS:

```
.indent { text-indent:-2em;margin-left:2em;  }

capitation span  {font-size:.8em;}
.bold { font-weight:bold; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin-left` for this:

```
<span style="font-size: 12px; margin-left: 5em;">ZZZZZ</span>
```

Note: If you want the same font size, wrap the `span` elements in a `div`:

```
<div style="font-size: 12px;"><span ...></div>
```

since the children of the `div` inherit its styles.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

putted tab 	 at start and after new line

```
<capitation>
<span class="bold">&#09;xxx</span>
<span>YYYY</span> 
<span class="bold">YYYYY</span> 
<span>YYYYY</span>
<br>

<span class="indent">&#09; XXXXXX</span> 
<span class="bold"> xxxxxxxx</span> 
<span>XXXXXXX</span>  
<br>
</capitation>
```